# Manager Class to handle multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I have multiple fragments which does the same thing but presented in different way to the user.  However, the functionality in all those fragments more like same as in delete, add etc.  That said, I do not want to duplicate the code.  Therefore created a manager class so that I could have the centralized code.  But, the problem now is, when the user is performing an action say, when the user is deleting an item, the fragment does not get refreshed.  So, I need to send the message to the fragment from the manager class to refresh the list.  I have the following pseudo code to give an insight...

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
ManagerClass mManagerClass;

private void onItemSelected() {
    mManagerClass = new ManagerClass(itemId);
}

public void refreshItems() {
    ItemDao.query();

}
```

}

```
public class ManagerClass {
public ManagerClass(int itemId) {
    DeleteItem(itemId);
}

private void DeleteItem(int itemId) {
    //when this task completes it should call the MrFragment.refreshItems();
    //Keep in mind that I cannot pass the Fragment becuse this ManagerClass is designed to handle more than two fragments
    //MAY BE I SHOULD DO CALLBACK BUT HOW?.... When i try to implement there several callbacks but not sure which one should I use and how...
}
```

}

```
Any help would be greatly appreciated...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so stupid and dumb at the time.  There are multiple ways to achieve this but the quick resolutions are:
1. Have a **ABSTRACT** class and extend the fragment out of it or
2. Use the **OBSERVER** pattern

I went with the second option, Observer pattern and works like a charm!